# Percona MySQL unable to start - ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, centos6, percona

BACKGROUND:

I installed Percona Server on a fresh Centos 6.4 minimal. Prior to this, I have never installed MySQL (though I'm not sure if Centos 6.4 minimal came with MySQL?)

Anyway, here are the commands I used:

```
rpm -Uhv http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
yum install Percona-Server-client-55 Percona-Server-server-55
```

Everything seems installed properly. However, I'm confused...

1) How come, unlike MySQL, did it not prompt me for creation of root password? How do I set the root password then?

2) When I tried starting Percona MySQL with the command "/etc/init.d/mysql start", it gave me the error:

Starting MySQL (Percona Server). ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/mail.example.com.pid)

Of course, here I used example.com in place of my real domain name.

Another thing: the "pid" file does not exist. Should it be there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

### EDIT:

As per the advice I got, I did a "ls -l /var/lib" and this is the folder permission of "/var/lib/mysql"

```
drwxr-xr-x. 4 mysql   mysql 4096 Apr 26 07:01 mysql
```

Not sure if this is the correct permission?

Comment: When you see an error like that, the first thing to do is look at the log file, you may be missing a file, or have wrong permissions on a directory, etc.

Comment: `grep mysql /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep denied` anything returned? could be selinux related, and no don't just turn it off, let's see if we can fix first :)

Comment: @Oneiroi, thanks for your help. No the grep did not return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  mysql_install_db
  chown -R mysql:mysql /yourdatadir
  service mysql start
```

This should do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Amralkar. In my case, is "/yourdatadir" = /var/lib/mysql ? Percona Server seems to have a default data directory of "/var/lib/mysql/data/", but in my case I don't have the "data" folder in /var/lib/mysql. Thanks for clarifications!

Comment: In other words, how do I know where my MySQL data directory is? Can I specify another folder? Or is it fixed? Where do I set it? Thanks!

Comment: By default mysql default data dir is /var/lib/mysql , and if any have changed data directory path then look in my.cnf file /etc/my.cnf for datadir paramater.

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Btw, I did "mysql_install_db" but not "chown -R mysql:mysql /yourdatadir" since the permission structure for the "/var/lib/mysql" is already correct (I think? See Edit above. Could you kindly verify?)

Comment: Yes that looks good.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set the root password then?

It's not uncommon for MySQL installations to ship like this - once you've got the server started, start mysql as root then change the passwd:

```
[root@yourbox ~]# mysql
....
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user 
SET Password=PASSWORD('cleartext password')
WHERE User='root';

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

As for fixing your error (which you'll need to do before changing the password) - this is usually caused by a permissions problem. Check that the directory /var/lib/mysql/ exists and is writeable by the dbms uid, and that the DBMS uid can write to the data files / directory. If still having a problem, check the mysql log and see if there is a file in the /var/lib/mysql/ directory with a .err extension.

Comment: Thank you, @symcbean. The directory exists, and I think the permission is ok, though I'm not sure. Please see my "Edit" above. Another thing: There is no file with ".err" extension in /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user running mysql (normally `mysql`) has permission to read/write/create files in all directories that are referenced in the configuration files.

If you have changed the location of log file to `/var/log/mysql`, for example, then then that directory should be owned by the `mysql` user.